# Complex roots forming a equilateral triangle

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Suppose we have relation 
$$z^2 + az + b=0 $$ where $a$ and $b$ are real and roots of this equation $z_1$ and $z_2$ form equilateral triangle with origin then what could be relation between $a$ and $b$ ? 
I simply applied quadratic formula in equation $$ z = \frac{-a \pm \sqrt{a^2 -4b}}{2} $$ now since it forms equilateral triangle with origin so $$|z_1| =|z_2|$$ applying which
$$( \frac{-a + \sqrt{a^2 -4b}}{2})^2= (\frac{-a - \sqrt{a^2 -4b}}{2})^2$$
 I arrived at $$a^2 = 4b$$ but my  answer is incorrect , why?

Comment: Are you given that $a$ and $b$ are real?

Comment: Yes they are real

Comment: It's hard to say what you did wrong, because you didn't show us your mistake.  You're right that $z=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-4b}}2$.  Butyou don't say how you got from there to $a^2=4b$.

Comment: Okay i have now edited my steps

Comment: The problem here is that $|z_1| = |z_2|$ is true whether or not the roots form an equilateral triangle; it is true whenever $z_1$ and $z_2$ are roots of the same quadratic, because the two roots are always conjugate.  But the equilateral triangle condition is stricter.

Comment: So maybe we need to apply theorem for rotation of complex numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint :

$z_1,z_2$ are complex numbers
$$(z-z_1)(z-z_2)=z^2+az+b$$
$$z_1+z_2=-a$$

$$z_1z_2=b$$

Because of equal triangle,
We know that $$z_1=M e^{i \alpha }$$
 $$z_2=M e^{i (\alpha+ \pi /3) }$$
 Thus you can use a relation between two complex numbers.

$$z_2/z_1=e^{i \pi /3}= \frac{ 1}{2}+i \frac{ \sqrt3}{2} $$

[image]

Comment: That picture is  very misleading, because $z_1$ and $z_2$ are conjugate.

Answer (score 2):

Hint;  The triangle in the complex plane whose verticies are the origin and the points $z_{1}$ and $z_{2}$ is equalateral if and only if
\begin{equation}
z_{1}+z_{2} = z_{1}z_{2}
\end{equation}
(Further hint: The reasoning behind this is that the distance from the origin to $z_{1}$ is $\sqrt{z_{1}\bar{z_{1}}}$ etc...)

Comment: Suppose $z_1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ and $z_2=1$. Then the right hand side is $z_1z_2=z_1=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$. That's not equal to the left hand side $z_1+z_2=\frac{3}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$.